# Uploading data from a lambda job to s3 is very slow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I’ve implemented an AWS lambda using Serverless framework to receive S3 `ObjectCreated` event and uncompress `tar.gz` files. I’m noticing that copying the extracted files in S3 takes a long time and times out. The `.tar.gz` file is ~ 18M in size and number of files in the compressed file is ~ `12000`. I’ve tried using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `500s` timeout. Any suggestions on how I can work around this issue

The lambda code implemented in python:
https://gist.github.com/arjunurs/7848137321148d9625891ecc1e3a9455

Answer (score 1):

In the gist that you have shared, there are a number of changes.

I suggest avoiding reading the extracted tar file in memory where you can stream stream its contents directly to the S3 bucket.

```py
def extract(filename):
    upload_status = 'success'
    try:
        s3.upload_fileobj(
            tardata.extractfile(filename),
            bucket,
            os.path.join(path, tarname, filename)
        )
    except Exception:
        logger.error(
            'Failed to upload %s in tarfile %s', 
            filename, tarname, exc_info=True)
        upload_status = 'fail'
    finally:
        return filename, upload_status
```

Comment: I get this when I don't read the extracted file in memory.
```
raise ValueError('Fileobj must implement read')
```

Comment: I'm unable to trace the error `tardata.extractfile(filename)` should return a `tarfile.ExFileObject` instance and that implements a `read` method. Where is the error coming from? Were you able to trace it?